# cookiecutter-django production build fails on `RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force` step

Tags: django, cookiecutter-django

Running `docker-compose -f production.yml build` fails at `Step 4/36 : RUN npm install && npm cache clean --force`.

It complains that "npm WARN deprecated set-value@2.0.0: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version."

I've had a look at what depends on set-value and it looks like there's 3 or 4 packages that require it.

Running this on local.yml warns but does not fail to build.

How do I force npm to request the latest version of 'set-value'?

Comment: I've tried updating the Dockerfile to include: `npm install --logevel=error && npm cache clean --force --logevel=error`, with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `set-value` is a nested dependency of the node dependencies, which are not kept very up to date, unfortunately.

I suggest you try looking at which ones are outdated using `npm outdated`, which you can do using the local node image: `docker-compose -f local.yml run node npm outdated`.

If you find the offending package, you can then update its version in the `package.json`. If not, maybe try to update everything would do the trick.

Finally, to avoid this pain to others or your future self, once/if you figure this out, I invite you to make the changes in the template itself. The [file to change is here](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/package.json), and I'll happily review the change or help you out.

**UPDATE:** This message `npm WARN deprecated set-value@2.0.0: Critical bug fixed in v3.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.` is just a warning though, and should not break the build. If you cannot build your prod image, there might be something else which is broken as I just tried and it worked fine, although I could see this warning.

Comment: Thanks @Bruno. As you've said it wasn't `set-value` that was causing the build to fail, however, issuing the command you suggested did result in me seeing the error that was the problem. It wasn't showing in logs previously. Thanks for you help!